# Between group differences where groups are unbalanced and composed of percentiles

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, python

I have two groups. Both groups are composed of percentiles based on a performance. I essentially want to test the null hypothesis that there are no differences between the groups. Ordinarily I would use a t-test but I don't think it is suitable given the nature of the percentiles.

The two groups represent the performances before and after an event and are unbalanced.

```
before_event = [35,67,45,63,45,67,56,67]
after_event = [34,23,21,3,65,46,52,24,56,76,52,12,15,16]
```

I'm looking for the best way to test for between group differences between the two groups and am looking for a solution in python or R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Wilcoxon rank-sum test (also known as a Mann-Whitney U test) to compare the difference in medians between two unbalanced groups. This test is a non-parametric alternative to the t-test and can be used when the assumption of normality is not met.

In R, you can perform a Wilcoxon rank-sum test using the function wilcox.test.

Here is an example of how you can perform the test:

```
before_event = c(35,67,45,63,45,67,56,67)
after_event = c(34,23,21,3,65,46,52,24,56,76,52,12,15,16)
wilcox.test(before_event, after_event, alternative="two.sided")
```

The output will give you the test statistic, p-value and the confidence interval. If the p-value is less than the significance level (e.g. 0.05), you can reject the null hypothesis and conclude that there is a significant difference in median between the two groups.

Or you can use Beta regression and estimate the effect of the event on the percentiles:

```
library(betareg)

before_event = c(35,67,45,63,45,67,56,67)/100
after_event = c(34,23,21,3,65,46,52,24,56,76,52,12,15,16)/100

data = data.frame(events= c(before_event, after_event), 
                  group = c(rep("0", length(before_event)), rep("1", length(after_event))))

model = betareg(events ~ group, data=data)
summary(model)
```